# Add wordwrap to decoded json text

Tags: php, json, word-wrap

I am using a simple script on my PHP webpage to decode and output JSON as text. However, what ever I try I can't get it to `wordwrap` the output.

```
$file = file_get_contents('sample.txt');
$out = (json_decode($file));
echo $out->mainText;
```

How can I get this script to `wordwrap` at 600 characters without chopping words in half?

If possible, can you show me the whole script please as I am slowly learning.

Thanks

Comment: What type is the value of `$out->mainText`?

Answer (score 3):

have a look at the [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function in php.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the code for you, but what you could do is cut of the text to 600 characters, which you do using `substr` and then see if the last character is a symbol like space, comma, period or whatever. If it isn't, try it at 599, then 598 etc. etc.

It's a better way to learn, by trying it yourself.

(added)
Ah I might have misread the question after seeing the other comment, in which case the `wordwrap` function that oedo mentioned might be all you need...

Comment: I have tried a couple of hundred ways to do this but each time it either fails or ends up in some sort of syntax error. I have tried even using tables but the text just heads west or disappears altogether.  

  Thanks all the same.

Comment: @Gary, before I say anything else: Do you want to cut the text at 600 characters without breaking words, or actually wrap it with a symbol (a newline or something)? Because if it's the latter, you should still look at PHP's `wordwrap` function, especially the last argument called `$cut` and what it does; namely what you want by default. http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

Comment: Hi Charles,
Would prefer to cut the text at 600 characters without breaking words.
  I think that I may have found the solution.
//<?php

$file = file_get_contents('warntest.txt');
 $out = (json_decode($file));
  echo $out->issuedAt;
//?>
//<?PHP 
echo wordwrap($out->mainText, 100, "<br>\n"); 
//?>

What it is is a 3 part file, issuedate, maintext and pic. I now realise where I was going wrong by not telling it what file/text to wrap.